# How can i achieve CoverFlow view

Tags: android, coverflow

I want to achieve overflow view with dotted layout.
Currently i am using polidea cover flow library URL [[gitHub]](https://github.com/Polidea/android-coverflow).
Using this library images are drawn at center.

I want to achieve exact UI like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

an excellent approach is given at https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow where

FancyCoverFlow in  Android app can be used as

```
fancyCoverFlow = new FancyCoverFlow(context);
fancyCoverFlow.setMaxRotation(45);
fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedAlpha(0.3f);
fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedSaturation(0.0f);
fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedScale(0.4f);
```

You can also inflate FancyCoverFlow from XML:

```
<at.technikum.mti.fancycoverflow.FancyCoverFlow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        fcf:maxRotation="45"
        fcf:unselectedAlpha="0.3"
        fcf:unselectedSaturation="0.0"
        fcf:unselectedScale="0.4" />
```

please visit also

1)https://github.com/deepwinter/android-coverflow

2)https://github.com/i7an/cover-flow-android

3)https://github.com/driventokill/android-coverflow

4)https://github.com/HelgePlaschke/Android-Cover-Flow-Widget

5)https://github.com/missingfeature/android-coverflow

Comment: Thanks Jitesh... Any Sample app with theses libraries ?

Comment: yes you can download them from github, just search there!!

Comment: one full code example is at http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/17/coverflow-android-complete-implementation-source-code/

Comment: How can i set hight and width for tablet ?

Comment: can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911244/fancycoverflow-layout-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score -1):

In Android You can chieve Cover flow Using ViewPager and Below code for

```
    fragmentimage.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.example.rajeev.viewpagercoverflow.CarouselLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pagerImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.example.rajeev.viewpagercoverflow.CarouselLinearLayout>
```

For more Detail You can visit to https://teachmeandroidhub.blogspot.com/2018/10/android-tutorial-how-to-create-view.html