# how to make custome Scroll for Image icons using horizontal scrollview android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I want to make custom Scroll for Image icons using horizontal scroll-view android , and zoom-in the icon that in front , and zoom-out the others like this picture [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely want to use one of the cover flow implementations on GitHub. SE answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290686/how-can-i-acheive-coverflow-view). You can also use the native ViewFlipper class in Android, which allows the use of a custom adapter and supports animations, etc., but it shows only one view at a time.

Comment: awesome , but i need to put custom icons on imageviews as u see in picture

Comment: I think you can. Have a look at their ViewGroup example (https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow/commit/806145e9636bed5ff3aea86a44c502541637256d). They show loading numberous images as resources, and it's customizable beyond that. I noticed that implementation is no longer maintained, but GitHub has others.