# Fancycoverflow layout not showing images properly

Tags: android, android-layout

I asked this same issue previously but could not get any answer properly,I am trying to implement fancy cover flow in my project but it does not show desired output,i am getting so much space between two images i follow this tutorial for that

https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow

I already asked question here

[Fancycoverflow layout is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911244/fancycoverflow-layout-is-not-working-properly)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancycoverflow layout is not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911244/fancycoverflow-layout-is-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your coverflow by using these functions:

```
fancyCoverFlow = (FancyCoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow_products);
fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedAlpha(1.0f);
fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedSaturation(1.0f);
fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedScale(1.0f);
fancyCoverFlow.setSpacing(10);
fancyCoverFlow.setMaxRotation(0);
fancyCoverFlow.setScaleDownGravity(0.01f);
fancyCoverFlow.setReflectionEnabled(true);
fancyCoverFlow.setReflectionRatio(0.000001f);
fancyCoverFlow.setReflectionGap(0);
fancyCoverFlow.setActionDistance(FancyCoverFlow.ACTION_DISTANCE_AUTO);
```